# Selecting one value from the dropdown

Tags: excel, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a value from dropdown list but my script keep on failing. the value that i am selecting is from Excel document with the '**Manager**' as the value.

**here is my xparth**

[image]

**And Here is my console**

[image]

i tried different solution but with no luck. the below code is the one i am trying that produced the error.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]")));
             select.deselectAll();
             select.selectByVisibleText(AGR);
```

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a conventional dropdown with select tag containing option tags but values in other div tags. You will have to write code to open the container and also select the option you want.

Comment: @Grasshopper how can i go about doing that. any examples might have can be useful. thank you in advanced. still new in automation

Comment: Locate the input element which contains the placeholder text "Please Select". Code to click on this element. A dropdown should appear. This is contained in the div with the class 'selectize-dropdown form-control single'. You should wait for the visibility of this div using an implicit wait. Finally locate the option you want to select which is in the div with the class 'selectize-dropdown-content', use the text you want to select as a locator strategy with xpath (text(),'blah blah'). Then click on this element. Should work if I am correct.

Comment: Make that explicit wait not implicit... Use ExpectedCondition visibilityOf()

Answer (score 0):

The code should be select.selectByVisisbleText("Manager"). Partial Text is not accepted.Complete text should be entered.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found solution to my problem. all i had to do is to find the xPath and send keys from the excel doc and click enter on the keyboard. this means i can change the name that is on the dropdown on the excel document, rather than hard code it on code.

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/input"));//You can use xpath, ID or name whatever you like
             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(AGR);
             webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

hope my solution can help any one experiencing the same issue.